# how to get elements in array inside object in php

Tags: php, rest

How do i get an request_vars from RestRequest Object..i want all the fields from an array.Below is the mentioned code

```
RestRequest Object
(
[request_vars:RestRequest:private] => Array
(
[{
"taskStmt":"demoo",
"description":"",
"projectId":"",
"assignedDate":"",
"endDate":"",
"TaskEffort":"",
"estimateTime":"",
"dependencies":_"",
"priority":"",
"timeTaken":"",
"workCompletion":"",
"status":"",
"user_id":"",
"mailsent":"",
"completiondate":""
}
] =>
)

[data:RestRequest:private] =>
[http_accept:RestRequest:private] => json
[method:RestRequest:private] => put
)
```

Comment: The array is `private` you need to access it via a public method

Answer (score 2):

According to your dump, **request_vars** is a private and no-static attribute.

So you need a getter method like this:

```
class RestRequest
{
    // ...

    public function getRequestVars()
    {
        return $this->request_vars;
    }
}
```

In this way you cannot edit/write the value of **request_vars** directly, but you can read it through the **getRequestVars()** public method:

```
var_dump( $object->getRequestVars() );
```

Comment: hey i have created RestRequest class and wrote this setter and getter but unable to retrive this data..please help?

Answer (score 1):

#### Update:

The examples you posted in comment have a `getRequestVars()` method on the class `RestRequest`, that should return those values.

You can get around visibility modifiers like `protected` and `private` with Reflection if you must, but probably not a good idea:

```
class Foo {
    public    $foo  = 1;
    protected $bar  = 2;
    private   $baz  = 3;
}

$foo = new Foo();

$reflect = new ReflectionClass($foo);
$props   = $reflect->getProperties();

foreach ($props as $prop) {
    $prop->setAccessible(true);
    print $prop->getName().' = '.$prop->getValue($foo)."\n";
}
```

Comment: I quote you... in fact reflection is slow and in this case a bad practice.

Comment: There's a `getRequestVars()` method on `RestRequest` class in the examples, that should return what you want.

Comment: As complex857 has said, in the RestRequest class of the example you linked there is already a getRequestVars() method like the code of my answer